# CSS hover doesn't work for hiding text in a spoiler

Tags: html, css, hover

What I want is that when I hover over the black bar the black turns into white so you can see the text.
This is my code:

```css
div.spoiler1:hover div.spoiler1 {
   background-color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div style='display:inline; background-color: black;' class='spoiler1'>hey</div>
```

I also tried this css:

```
spoiler1:hover spoiler1 {
   background-color: white;
 }
```

```
div.spoiler1:hover,.spoiler1 {
   background-color: white;
 }
```

```
spoiler1:hover {
   background-color: white;
 }
```

Comment: `div.spoiler1:hover div.spoiler1` won't work because it's trying to select a div with the class of spoiler1 which is a descendant of an ancestor div with the same class that's being hovered. That doesn't exist in your HTML example. `spoiler1:hover spoiler1` fails for a similar reason but more so because it's looking for an actual spolier1 element and none exist. `div.spoiler1:hover,.spoiler1` is a mashup of the previous two mistakes, and `spoiler1:hover` fails because of the same second error. You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good efforts. The issue is that the inline style overrides the sheet. In general, don't use inline styles (hard to debug/maintain, not reusable):

```css
div.spoiler1 {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline;
}

div.spoiler1:hover {
   background-color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div class='spoiler1'>hey</div>
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm0nxfr1/1/).

Comment: Yes thanks, i am doing this with php that is why i used  inline style, but i keep this in mind. Thanks for awnsering so fast!